# Unit Testing WCF Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, c#-4.0

Im writting unit test for a WCF service which i have written. The thing is when i run the Unit test it throw me error saying that there is no end point listening.  I need to compile my WCF Service and later run the unit test.

Is there any other way where Unit Test runs and host the WCF service and later start testing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running a test against an actual WCF service would not be unit testing, it would be *integration* testing; if you want to do this you'd do it as part of an automated build process which deploys the service and then runs your tests.

To *unit* test your service, you should ignore the WCF aspect and call the service class directly, as if it were any other class.